# Remove the # hash from URL when using Vue.js in Laravel Homestead

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes, vue.js, homestead

I have a Laravel 5.2 setup running in Homestead and using Vue.js router to build an SPA. I'm trying to completely remove the #hash from the URL which I know can be done, but I keep getting errors:

I've added `rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;` to my vhosts file in Homestead:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name app.myproject.dev;
    root "/home/vagrant/Code/vibecast/app.myproject.com/public";

    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    ...

}
```

When I restart and open a page I get a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Is there anything I need added to routes in Laravel?

```
var router = new VueRouter({
    hashbang: false,
    history: true,
    linkActiveClass: "active"
})
```

I can get it working without the #hash (or the modified hosts file) when navigating around, but fails when I reload a page.

Comment: You could add a get route at the end of your routes file with this as route `'/{a?}/{b?}/{c?}/{d?}/{e?}/{f?}/{g?}/'` making you able to register api routes bevore it.

Comment: Thanks. In what context do I add that in the routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution, via Matt Stauffer's demo app. First, no need to update vhosts file. Just need to update the SPA/Vue.js route in `routes.php` to:

```
Route::get('/{vue?}', 'AppController@spa')->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

If you have an admin panel and do not want to consider its prefix

```
Route::get('/{vue?}', 'AppController@spa')->where('vue','^(?!panel).*$');
```

---

And of course initialise the Vue.js router like so:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    history: true,
    hashbang: false,
    linkActiveClass: 'active'
})
router.mode = 'html5'
```

Ref: https://github.com/mattstauffer/suggestive/blob/master/app/Http/routes.php#L9

Comment: Probably, `html5` mode renamed to `history`. See http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

```export default new Router({mode: 'history' }); ```

Answer (score 9):

You can make Vue Router and Laravel Router work together nicely by making the following changes:

**At the end** of your `routes/web.php` add the next lines:

```
Route::get('{path}', function() {
  return view('your-vuejs-main-blade');
})->where('path', '.*');
```

You need to add this at the end of file because you need to preserve the previously declared laravel routes in order to work properly and not be overwritten by the 404 page or vue-router's paths.

In your Vue router's config use the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
    mode: 'history', //removes # (hashtag) from url
    base: '/',
    fallback: true, //router should fallback to hash (#) mode when the browser does not support history.pushState
    routes: [
        { path: '*', require('../components/pages/NotFound.vue') },
        //... + all your other paths here
    ]
})
export default router
```

However, when navigating between laravel and vue-router, you need to keep in mind that leaving vue-router's page to a laravel page you must use a `window.location.href` code, an `<a>` tag or some sort of [programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html) in order to fully exit Vue-router's instance.

Tested this with Laravel 5.5.23, Vue 2.5.9, Vue-Router 3.0.1

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the router mode to `html5` RE: http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/api/properties.html

So your new code would be like:

```
var router = new VueRouter({
    hashbang: false,
    history: true,
    linkActiveClass: "active"
})
router.mode = 'html5'
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not actually clear how to implement it? Apologies, still learning the router :/

Comment: @JackBarham added code to show how it would be used :)

Comment: Ahh I see now. Got it working, but now when I refresh I get a "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found". Does anything need to be updated within Laravel routes?

Comment: You probably need a catch all that sends you to the view that you initiate Vue in. I'm not familiar with Laravel but here is how i do it in Django: https://github.com/dan-gamble/fifa/blob/develop/fifa/urls.py#L19

Comment: Yeah, sounds about right, I'll check it out. Btw, your Vue setup on that repo is really handy as a reference guide ;)

Comment: It's mainly from here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/dev/example/advanced But happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

export default new Router({
mode: 'history', // https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode
linkActiveClass: 'active',
})

Answer (score 1):

Laravel router

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
     return view('welcome');})->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

Vue-router

```
export default new Router({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeView },
        { path: '/category', name: 'Category', component: CategoryView },
        { path: '/topic', name: 'Topci', component: TopicView }
    ],
    mode: 'history'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to your Laravel web.php

```
Route::get('/{vue?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\AppController@index')->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Vue-Router

```
const router = new VueRouter({
            mode: 'history',
            routes,

        })
```